# Exception while using ExecuteQuery() in Silverlight client object model

Tags: silverlight, sharepoint, object, model, client

I have been developing a Silverlight user control for SharePoint using the Client Object model. Here is the coding

```
            InitializeComponent();
            ctx = ClientContext.Current;
            Web web = ctx.Web;
            ctx.Load(web, oweb => oweb.Title);
            ctx.Load(web, oweb => oweb.Lists);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

I heard tht SIlverlight supports both ExecuteQuery() and ExecuteQueryAsync() methods. But I'm getting an Exception message like this "he method or property that is called may block the UI thread and it is not allowed. Please use background thread to invoke the method or property, for example, using System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem method to invoke the method or property."

Can anyone tell me where am I going wrong and how to use ExecuteQuery() method ?? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be off base here, but as I understand it, ExecuteQuery() requires you to create a thread so you aren't calling a stop to the UI thread when you invoke the method. The reason you use ExecuteQueryAsync is exactly that: ExecuteQueryAsync performs the operation on a seperate thread, then you just call back in to the UI thread using the dispather:

```
ctx.ExecuteQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded, onQueryFailed);
```

...

```
 private void onQuerySucceeded(object sender, ClientRequestSucceededEventArgs args)
 {
 this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
            {
doStuff();
}));
}
```